# Cannot access .env variables in react app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, environment-variables

I am trying to access the .env variable from the src folder in the frontend files but it keeps giving me undefined for some reason.
The env variable is :
REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL=http://localhost:5000 .

here is the folder structure:

[image: Click!]

Comment: I believe you created your `frontend` using `create-react-app`

Try moving your `.env` file inside the frontend folder.

Comment: If you need server-side values in your client-side code, either configure your bundler so that it can make that happen, or give the server a `/config.json` endpoint or the like so it can respond with the up-to-date values your client needs. Either way: _do not expose values that are in any way sensitive_ like cookie secrets, auth tokens, etc.

Comment: Hey! @shet_tayyy if i do that, ill lose access to the variable i made for the backend part. Is it okay to make two .env files?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans ok. But how do i solve the problem in hand?

Comment: Probably first by reading https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables

Comment: @ZohebAhmed There is absolutely no harm in creating different env files for 2 different environments